# How to delete all except for 2 specific items in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete all users from mysql.user
except for the users "1" and "2";

i ran this command but it also deleted the user "1" and "2";

```
 mysql> delete from mysql.user where user!='1' or user!='2';
```

i also tried

```
 mysql> delete from mysql.user where (user!='1' or user!='2');
```

same result, the user '1' and '2' are being deleted.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `AND`?

Comment: i think "AND" is where multi conditions for the same row.

Comment: AND Works -- see my answer below...

Comment: Just think of it in terms of the English language: "Delete from user where user does not equal 1 and user does not equal 2."  In the case of `OR` it would say "...does not equal 1 *or* user does not equal 2."  If user is 1, it satisfies the "does not equal 2" condition and vice versa.

Comment: okay i tested it, `AND` actually works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should work using `NOT IN`:

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user where user NOT IN (1,2)
```

The problem with your query is the `OR` -- it is removing the other because 1 isn't equal to 2 and vice versa.

Your query would work with `AND`:

```
delete from mysql.user where (user!='1' AND user!='2');
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ab38/1)

vs:

[SQL Fiddle Demo with Or](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6717/1)

Comment: thanks, i am going with `AND` given that it is more inline with logic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NOT IN`

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user NOT IN (1, 2)
```

The reason why both are included is simple. `1 <> 2` and `2 <> 1`.

Comment: @SumerKolcak `<>` means "not equal to"

Comment: i had no idea `<>` meant 'not equal to', they look like 'bigger than' and 'smaller than' symbols. i guess the world has advanced.

Answer (score 2):

delete from mysql.user where user not in ('1','2')

Comment: amazing, this works also but i prefer `AND` because codes really need to make sense. i even thought it should have been `OR` for it to be really logical.